# Pass order directly and skip checkout and payment method

Tags: magento2

I have two groups of customer so according to customer group:if customer from group 1 so skip payment and checkout step so when he click go on checkout he directly place order and it's saved else if customer from group 2 then he should have the checkout and payment method step so how to proceed step by step thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to apply "Cash on Delivery Payment" method to the customers of group 1. So, they can skip the payment method. Follow these steps:

1. Head to **Admin > System > Configuration**.
2. Select **Payment Methods**.
3. In right panel, you will get option "**Cash on Delivery Payment**."
4. Choose "**Yes**" from drop-down.

Comment: but how to apply that just for group 1